# java asterisk right triangle

Tags: java

I'd like to try a right triangle asterisk. But I only got this 
**output:** (I can't place here the asterisk)

```
@ 
@@
@@@
```

what I want is this:

```
  @
 @@
@@@
```

Here's the code that I programmed:

```
 public class triangles {
public static void main( String[] args ) {

    for( int i = 1; i <= 10; i++ ){
        for( int j = 0; j < i; j++ ){
            System.out.print("*");

        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
  }
```

Any ideas to share are greatly appreciated. I'm a java newbie. thanks.

Comment: I'm confused. It looks like your desired and actual output is the same...

Comment: @mikeTheLiar That's probably due to a badly formatted question, rather than them actually being the same.

Comment: Im guessing it doesnt render on her properly either.  Are the *'s meant to be on seperate lines so the first is on its own then the two are offset left and right by one space line below?

Comment: Hey guys sorry I already edited it.

Comment: Unless I've gotten myself very confused, the code you posted looks like it's going to do the longer lines first, so your triangle would be in effect upside-down relative to what you say you want.

Comment: Hi @FahimParkar, no this is not a homework. I'm just solving a Java problem.

Comment: @FahimParkar thanks. I love coding as well, and trying Java again..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code never prints any spaces, that should be a problem.

You can use this simple approach:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) System.out.println("  @@@".substring(i, i+3));
```

The logic is quite simple: you have the string with two spaces and three at-signs. The first line of output needs to be two spaces and a single at-sign, so that's the first three chars of the string. The second line should be one space and two at-signs—that's the three chars of the string after skipping the first one; and so on: you just slide through the string, each time skipping one more from the beginning and taking the next three chars.

### [Demo](http://ideone.com/ozVGH)

Answer (score 4):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    for(int j = 9; j > 0; j--)
        System.out.print(i < j ? " " : "*");

    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @mikeTheLiar, I'll try to get the logic behind your code. I'll get back to you if I don't understand some lines.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are not outputting any white space.  Calculate how much whitespace you need to offset each line first, output this white space then output your *'s

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Star2 {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {

        InputStreamReader read = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(read);
        int i,j,n=0,k;
        System.out.print("How many stars you want to print in first row ? ");
        n=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        for (i = 0; i<n; i=i+2)
        {
            for (j=i; j<n;j++)
            System.out.print ("*");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
public class PrintPyramidStar {  

   public static void main(String args[]) {  

    int c = 1;  
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {  
        for (int j = i; j < 5; j++) {  
            System.out.print(" ");
        }  
        for (int k = 1; k <= c; k++) {  
            if (k % 2 == 0)  
                System.out.print(" ");  
            else  
                System.out.print("*");  
        }  
        System.out.println();  
        c += 2;  
    }  
  }  
}
```