# How do you create a java loop that creates a Triangle with squared numbers?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I have searched far and wide for information on this subject to no avail. I am really struggling with Java Loops.

I get the big picture ideas of For/While loops, but when it comes time to actually start programming, I get error after error...

I have tried writing out my program and understanding the logic of it, but I cannot seem to get the program to do what I want it to do.

The task at hand:

> Write a program using a Scanner that asks the user for a number n between 1 and 9 (inclusive).  The program prints a triangle with n rows.  The first row contains only the square of 1, and it is right-justified.  The second row contains the square of 2 followed by the square of 1, and is right justified.  Subsequent rows include the squares of 3, 2, and 1, and then 4, 3, 2 and 1, and so forth until n rows are printed.
>
> Assuming the user enters 4, the program prints the following triangle to the console
>
> ```
>           1
>        4  1
>     9  4  1
> 16  9  4  1
> ```
>
> For full credit, each column should be 3 characters wide and the values should be right justified.

So far, I have come close (not including the user input for now, just trying to at least get a grasp on the looping aspect and then I will work on that):

```
public class MyClass { 
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int rows = 4; // this is the value that the user will enter for # of rows
        for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
            for (int j = i; j >= 1; j--) {
                System.out.print((j*j)+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

PRINTS:

```
 1
 4 1
 9 4 1
 16 9 4 1
```

Comment: Is your problem that your triangle is inverted/mirrored? Did you try inverting your inner loop so that you're starting at 1 and incrementing to `i` instead of starting at `i` and decrementing to 1?

Comment: I don't think it's inverted, just that there isn't enough whitespace to push the above rows into place. For example, the bottom row is perfect, not inverted.

Comment: Since this is a homework problem I don't think we should give you the answer.  Here is some info on creating a right justified triangle: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11542113/java-asterisk-right-triangle

Comment: I appreciate the answers everyone! this is my first time on stackoverflow, I never felt it was right to ask for help on homework questions but this one really got me for some reason. Loops send me for a loop... (;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int rows = 4; // this is the value that the user will enter for # of rows

for (int i = rows; i > 0; i--) {
    for (int j = rows; j > 0; j--)
        System.out.print((rows - j + 1) < i ? "   " : String.format("%3d", j * j));
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I honestly have been given no information about formats until stumbling across them moments before reading this. You honestly helped me out, thank you. I wasn't just asking for the answer everyone I really need help when it comes to looping in general.

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems.

First, you need the numbers printed with padding on the left to produce the number in the space of 3 characters.  Look at [`System.out.printf("%3d", ...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...))

Second, you need to print out additional blank columns.  3 blank columns on the first row, two blank columns on the second row, 1 blank column on the third row, and zero blank columns on the last row.  Sounds like another inner loop.

Answer (score 1):

You actually need to print a square table, not a triangle. It's just that some of the cells in the table will be filled with spaces.

This means that your algorithm should be something like this:

```
for row from 1 to n
    for col from n to 1 /* Note: It's not from row to 1 */
        if col <= row print square(col)
        else print pad
```

Comment: I honestly did not know that this was a square table, thank you for the information. I am struggling with loops and always have.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TriangleOfSquares {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter an integer between 1 and 9: ");
        int n = input.nextInt();
        for (int i = n; i > 0; i--) {
            for (int j = n; j > 0; j--)
                System.out.print((n - j + 1) < i ? "   " : String.format("%3d", j * j));
            System.out.println();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.